# How to use the python code in React Native app?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, react-native, transcrypt

I want to use React Native as a front-end and the core logic to implement in python. How it can be implemented? Is there a python wrapper
for js, with support for react native

Comment: You could use your Python back-end as a normal rest API for your client-side react. "How can it be implemented" is a bit too broad of a question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org). It supports React, including [compilation of JSX](http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/special_facilities.html#using-an-external-transpiler-pragma-xtrans-translator-cwd-workingdirectory) source embedded in Python.

Disclaimer: I am the initiator of the project.